# The relation of $P(X=x+1)$ and $P(X=x)$ in binomial distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, binomial-theorem

[image]

If I substitute the values to the binomial probability theory, it appears as such

$${n \choose x+1} p^{x+1} (1-p)^{n-x-1}$$

I don't know how to move on...

What am I doing wrong, or are you expected to approach this some other way?

Comment: You are supposed to **divide** P(X=x+1) **by** P(X=x)...

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\require{cancel}
\Pr[X=x]&={n\choose {x}}p^{x}(1-p)^{n-x}\\
\Pr[X=x+1]&={n\choose {x+1}}p^{x+1}(1-p)^{n-(x+1)}\\
&={n\choose x+1}\left(\dfrac  p{1-p}\right) p^x(1-p)^{n-x}\\
&={n\choose x+1}\left(\dfrac p{1-p}\right)\dfrac{\Pr[X=x]}{n\choose x}\\
&=\dfrac {n\choose x+1}{n\choose x}\left(\dfrac p{1-p}\right)\Pr[X=x]\\
&=\dfrac {\left[\dfrac {\cancel{n!}}{(x+1)!(n-x-1)!}\right]}{\left[\dfrac {\cancel{n!}}{x!(n-x)!}\right]}
\left(\dfrac p{1-p}\right)\Pr[X=x]\\
&=\dfrac{x!(n-x)!}{(x+1)!(n-x-1)!}\left(\dfrac p{1-p}\right)\Pr[X=x]\\
&=\dfrac{\cancel{x!}\left[(n-x)\cancel{(n-x-1)!}\right]}{\left[(x+1)\cancel{x!}\right]\cancel{(n-x-1)!}}\left(\dfrac p{1-p}\right)\Pr[X=x]\\
&=\left(\dfrac {n-x}{x+1}\right)\left(\dfrac p{1-p}\right)\Pr[X=x]
\qquad \blacksquare
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Recall that if $X \sim \mathrm{Binomial}(n,p)$, then $$\Pr[X = x] = \binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x}, \quad x = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, n.$$  Then use this to calculate the ratio $$\frac{\Pr[X = x+1]}{\Pr[X = x]},$$ being careful to cancel like terms.

Comment: why do we calculate a ratio?

Comment: Why not try it and see what happens?  Often, it is through computation that we develop intuition about why we approach certain problems in a particular way.